# Adding Vue only to some parts of an existing application

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

I see that html files in examples with Vue consist only of one root "div" element with "app" id and actually no more elements in the file. HTML elements inside are rendered as templates in js (or vue) files. And it is fine for SPA.

However, I have a multi-page application which is rendered and routed in backend (PHP) and I don't want to change it. But I would like to use Vue for some reactive elements only (e.g wizard) in the application keeping the other pages and routing as they are.

What is the best practice for it?

A) Creating a new Vue instance for every element I need. So it would be look like:

```
<body>
 <header></header>
 <div>
 ... other html elements ...
 <div id="vue_wizard>
   <div> 
   Could I place the html elements for the wizard here or should I render them in VUE JS files?
   </div>
 </div>
 ... other html elements ...
 </div>
 <footer></footer>
</body>
```

B) Actually I don't have any other idea for it.

Comment: Totally depends on your case. There are several options. Can you explain it in details? Which elements, and how they are supposed to be related to data from PHP. It's more straightforward to keep all components inside Vue but then "ould I place the html elements" content won't be available for SEO, unless you do SSR.

Comment: The case is pretty simple: I have existing PHP Web-app and I'd like to add several forms and wizards that will be possible to be edited inline (without refreshing the page). I don't want to use jquery for that and I would like to use the opportunity to try it with vue.js

Comment: It's simple but specific to your case. If's unknown if the same part is supposed to be used multiple times per page. Basically the choice is either Vue sub-apps or web components. And with subapps they can be either proper Vue CLI apps or Vue components with inline templates (see how Vue is used with PHP).